# ASP.Net MVC 4 WebAPI Custom Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller called News in my WebAPI project, I have two default actions called Get that handled the following URL's:

/api/News <- this returns a list of news
/api/News/123 <- this returns a specific news item by id.

All straightforward so far and obviously the default route handles these scenarios. I next want to have a URL that looks like this:

/api/News/123/Artists <- will return all artists related to the specified news item.

Now I am fairly news to ASP.Net MVC and WebAPI so this is the first time I have had to deal with routing. I have modified my default route to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

So here I have moved the {action} to the end of the URL and I have added a Artists method to my News controller. This still works with the first two scenarios but returns a 404 for the third scenario.

Obviously the routing isn't working for /api/News/123/Artists but I have no idea why.

I can't seem to find any examples of people using WebAPI like this which makes me think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is, that you are trying to acces *Web API* but mapping the **ASP.NET MVC**

this is a mapping you need:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
  defaults: new {controller = "News", action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
  );
```

And it should be done in the `App_Start \ WebApiConfig` (if using the default template settings)

Example of the methods (in your news API controller):

```
// GET api/values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
  return "value " + id;
}

// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet]
public string Artist(int id)
{
  return "artist " + id;
}
```

Comment: AH! Your right, I immediately went to the RouteConfig class and not the WebApiConfig class. Put this down to a WebAPI rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

The [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) should be a good solution. It can be installed by `Nuget`, and the document is [here](http://attributerouting.net/).

## Some examples

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [GET("Sample")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }
                    
    [POST("Sample")]
    public ActionResult Create() { /* ... */ }
                    
    [PUT("Sample/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Update(int id) { /* ... */ }
                    
    [DELETE("Sample/{id}")]
    public string Destroy(int id) { /* ... */ }
    
    [Route("Sample/Any-Method-Will-Do")]
    public string Wildman() { /* ... */ }

    [GET("", ActionPrecedence = 1)]
    [GET("Posts")]
    [GET("Posts/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }

    [GET("Demographics/{state=MT}/{city=Missoula}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string state, string city) { /* ... */ }
}
```

It works very well about `custom routing`.

### Update

[In asp.net WebApi 2, AttributeRouting is included inside by native.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) It has some history, the first version, `asp.net WebApi 1`, is weak about routing annotations.

And then, `asp.net WebApi 2` is released, the `AttributeRouting` is included by native. So, that open project is not maintained anymore, said in [GitHub page](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting).

[In microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/interoperability/2013/11/14/showcasing-open-source-community-contributors-to-entity-framework-asp-net-and-web-api-for-visual-studio/), the section `Independent Developer Profile – Tim McCall – Attribute Routing in MVC and Web API 2` said about the history too.

Comment: Down voted for recommending a third party solution to solve a simple misunderstanding with the framework. It works fine OOTB.

Comment: [In asp.net WebApi 2, the attribute routing is included.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 1):

In routing Action is the action name on the method that you want to route to .That action name should be in the attribute used on the method.

```
 [HttpGet]
 [ActionName("CustomAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage MyNewsFeed(Some params)
{ return Request.CreateResponse(); }
```

Now your route should look like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "CustomAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional
```

Let me know if this helps.